# React Router ScrollToTop not working with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm using Material UI for a fairly simple website but I'm having trouble with ScrollToTop. I've followed the documentation but can't seem to find the issue with my code. The desired functionality is every time a link is clicked, the page loads at the top. Instead, when clicked, the page changes but is rendered in the same position as the previous. See below - I've simplified the code so you aren't blasted with a wall of text.

Documentation referenced: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration

Root Component

```
const homePage = () => (<Home />);
const helpPage = () => (<Help />);
const termsPage = () => (<Markdown>{terms}</Markdown>);
const privacyPage = () => (<Markdown>{privacy}</Markdown>);

class Header extends React.Component {

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <AppBar position="absolute" className={classes.appBar}>
            <Toolbar>
              <Link className={classes.link} to="/"><Typography>Home</Typography></Link>
              <Link className={classes.link} to="/help"><Typography>Help</Typography></Link>
              <IconButton onClick={this.props.logOut} className={classes.headerIcon}>
                <AccountCircleIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <main className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={homePage} />
            <Route path="/help" component={helpPage} />
            <Route path="/terms" component={termsPage} />
            <Route path="/privacy" component={privacyPage} />
            <Footer />
          </main>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the root of the issue. The ScrollToTop function was referencing the `window`, but the content in question was being rendered in the `main` element under the Material UI Header. My solution was to reference the `main` element - problem solved. See below.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  main = null;

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.main.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <AppBar position="absolute" className={classes.appBar}>
            <Toolbar>
              <Link className={classes.link} to="/"><Typography>Home</Typography></Link>
              <Link className={classes.link} to="/help"><Typography>Help</Typography></Link>
              <IconButton onClick={this.props.logOut} className={classes.headerIcon}>
                <AccountCircleIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <main ref={(ref) => { this.main = ref; }} className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={homePage} />
            <Route path="/help" component={helpPage} />
            <Route path="/terms" component={termsPage} />
            <Route path="/privacy" component={privacyPage} />
            <Footer />
          </main>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

----Edits----
Using React.createRef() as suggested by Pier

```
class Header extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.main = null;
    this.setMainRef = (element) => {
      this.main = element;
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.main.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <AppBar position="absolute" className={classes.appBar}>
            <Toolbar>
              <Link className={classes.link} to="/"><Typography>Home</Typography></Link>
              <Link className={classes.link} to="/help"><Typography>Help</Typography></Link>
              <IconButton onClick={this.props.logOut} className={classes.headerIcon}>
                <AccountCircleIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <main ref={this.setMainRef} className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={homePage} />
            <Route path="/help" component={helpPage} />
            <Route path="/terms" component={termsPage} />
            <Route path="/privacy" component={privacyPage} />
            <Footer />
          </main>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: May I suggest to use `React.createRef` insteaf of an arrow ref?

Comment: Great suggestion. I'll update my answer with this alternative.